# What is the model name of video camera that filmed the lunar lift-off?

Tags: the-moon

The timing is supposedly pretty interesting also, but that is not the question. I'm asking about the lunar lift-off.

I'm interested in knowing if it was also a Hasselblad video camera, if that even exists, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10):

The liftoffs were viewed using the TV cameras mounted on the rovers.  These cameras were [made by RCA](http://airandspace.si.edu/collections/artifact.cfm?object=nasm_A19850021000).  The "model name" was [RCA J-Series Ground-Commanded Television Assembly.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_TV_camera)  The operations and checkout manual for the camera can be read [here](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/GCTA-Manual.pdf).  This is an image of the cover of the manual.

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting, thank you. Can you tell me if this camera set-up can withstand temperatures of over 150° ?